# Nvidia device missing after rebooting in Linux

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I have a PC equipped with three NVIDIA graphics cards, and the OS is Cent OS 7. I have installed NVIDIA driver as well as CUDA toolkit.

Normally, in `/dev/`, there are several nvidia devices:

`/dev/nvidia0
/dev/nvidia1
/dev/nvidia2
/dev/nvidiactl
/dev/nvidia-uvm
/dev/nvidia-uvm-tools
/dev/nvram`

However, once I reboot the PC, all of the devices mentioned above are lost. So I am wondering what the problem is, and how to re-generate these devices after rebooting without re-installing the driver or CUDA toolkit.

Comment: This issue still exists. After multiple reboots at one point it creates those devices in /dev 
NVIDIA installation is just not worth it. switch to radeon graphics driver. its much more easier.